# Optimizing and Improving Python Code that Models the 3D Trajectory of a Thrown Baseball

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, data-modeling

I've been working on learning Python as I feel I need to expand my knowledge of programming languages. After reading up and watching a few tutorials, I came up with a basic program that models a baseball thrown from the pitchers mound to home plate with numpy and maplotlib. As i have just began learning python, I do not believe my code is all that great.

The first thing I ask is and suggestions for improvements. I would like to optimize this before I start adding to it. Any links provided or just general help would be great.

Second, is using matplotlib the best way to go about this is or is there something else you would suggest?

Third, I would like to add a pitching mound, just a simple semisphere, into the program, could someone point me in the right direction to go on with that?

Thanks, any and all help/guidance/comments is appreciated!

I will include the functions in my code that I would like to improve.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

#stike zone
def strike_zone():
    x_zone =        [0,0]
    z_sides =       [1.5, 3.5]
    y_right =       [-1, -1]
    y_right_mid =   [-.333,-.333]
    y_left =        [1,1]
    y_left_mid =    [.333,.333]
    y_sides =       [-1,1]
    z_top =         [3.5,3.5]
    z_mid_top =     [2.833,2.833]
    z_mid_bottom =  [2.167,2.167]
    z_bottom =      [1.5,1.5]
    ax1.plot(x_zone,y_left, z_sides, color = 'r',linewidth = 2) #left side
    ax1.plot(x_zone, y_right, z_sides, color = 'r',linewidth = 2) #right side
    ax1.plot(x_zone, y_right_mid, z_sides, color = 'r',linewidth = 1) #right mid side
    ax1.plot(x_zone, y_left_mid, z_sides, color = 'r',linewidth = 1) #left mid side
    ax1.plot(x_zone, y_sides, z_top, color = 'r',linewidth = 2) #top side
    ax1.plot(x_zone, y_sides, z_mid_top, color = 'r',linewidth = 1) #top middle
    ax1.plot(x_zone, y_sides, z_mid_bottom, color = 'r',linewidth = 1) #bottom middle
    ax1.plot(x_zone, y_sides, z_bottom, color = 'r',linewidth = 2) #bottom side

#Field
def field():
    #FoulLines
    x_Rline = [0,63.5]
    x_Lline = [0,63.5]
    y_Rline = [0,63.5]
    y_Lline = [0, -63.5]
    ax1.plot(x_Rline,y_Rline, color = '#696969')
    ax1.plot(x_Lline,y_Lline, color = '#696969')

    #home plate
    front_line_x = [1.417,1.417]
    front_line_y = [-.71,.71]
    right_side_x = [1.417,.707]
    right_side_y = [.71,.71]
    left_side_x = [1.417,.707]
    left_side_y = [-.71,-.71]
    right_diag_x = [.707,0]
    right_diag_y = [.71,0]
    left_diag_x = [.707,0]
    left_diag_y = [-.71,0]
    ax1.plot(front_line_x,front_line_y, color = 'k', linewidth = 2)
    ax1.plot(right_side_x,right_side_y,color = 'k', linewidth = 2)
    ax1.plot(left_side_x,left_side_y,color = 'k', linewidth = 2)
    ax1.plot(right_diag_x,right_diag_y,color = 'k', linewidth = 2)
    ax1.plot(left_diag_x,left_diag_y,color = 'k', linewidth = 2)

#draw pitch
def draw_pitch():
    x,y,z = np.loadtxt('test.txt', delimiter = '    ', unpack = True)
    ax1.plot(x,y,z,
        color = 'c',
        linewidth = 5.5,
        solid_capstyle = 'round')
```